# Character matrix to numeric matrix for heatmap

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, bioinformatics, heatmap

I have created a heatmap for the top 100 differentially expressed transcripts with EnsembIDs and three samples (RNA-seq -> kallisto -> sleuth) .

```
library(gplots) # heatmap.2
library(dplyr) # unite

heatmap.2(log(tmp_df+1), trace="none", density.info="none", scale="row")
```

Now I am interested to add gene names in the heatmap for e.g. EnsemblD_genename. For this purpose, I have proceeded as follows:

1) Created "ext_gene" column in tmp_df

```
tmp_df["ext_gene"] <- NA
```

2) Matched target_id from tmp_df with target_id of top_100new (containing ext_gene)

```
tmp_df$ext_gene <- top_100new$ext_gene[match(tmp_df$target_id, top_100new$target_id)]
```

3) Merged target_id and ext_gene columns in tmp_df (target_id__ext_gene column in place of target_id and ext_gene columns)

```
unite <- unite(tmp_df, target_id__ext_gene, target_id, ext_gene, sep='_')
```

4) I was unable to convert "unite" to numeric matrix because one column "target_id__ext_gene" has NA in some rows for e.g. ENSEMBL00001_NA, so I tried to replace NA with NONE.

```
unite$target_id__ext_gene <- gsub ('NA', 'NONE', unite$target_id__ext_gene)
```

5) But, still I am unable to convert "unite" into numeric matrix because column "target_id__ext_gene" has character class. I have tried to use

```
unite$target_id__ext_gene <- as.numeric(as.character(unite$target_id__ext_gene))
```

but, it converts all rows of column "target_id__ext_gene" into NA (`NAs introduced by coercion`)

I know that numeric object can be passed to heatmap.2 and there only I am stuck because of one character column.

This is how my data looks like by using reproduce(unite):

```
                   target_id__ext_gene      T2   Npt3         n1   Npt1   Npt2        T3
    1)             ENS00000112_NONE 5239.1161 0.000000e+00 1.117028e+03 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 3905.476311
    2)             ENS00000150_tfb2m  771.3926 1.012137e+03 4.132779e-06 7.785302e+02 7.625490e+02  634.195429
...
    99)             ENS00000130_NONE  136.2607 1.658801e+00 1.498763e+02 2.733379e+00 0.000000e+00   64.313849
    100)            ENS00000124_NONE  606.0573 1.155628e+02 3.062783e+02 1.054907e+02 1.084090e+02  430.250175

               n3         n2         T1
1)   1.327292e+03 1.401719e+03 4230.5667240
2)   1.561575e-06 1.113367e-06  526.1571307
...
99)  1.511978e+02 1.240264e+02   68.4360589
100) 3.817887e+02 4.725010e+02  636.0279422
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: There is no need for "step 1".

Comment: @zx8754, I just wanted to give full details from beginning.

Comment: No worries, good you shared all the details, I am simply stating it could be simplified.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @zx8754 updated the post with how my data looks like.

Comment: Is `heatmap.2` not from `gplots` package?

Comment: @zx8754 It is from gplots package.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely that `heatmap.2` requires a numeric matrix and is expecting the rownames to serve as labels. You can accomplish that from your data, however, without setting the rownames.

First, some actual reproducible data:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    target_id__ext_gene = LETTERS
    , matrix(rnorm(26*6, 50, 5)
             , nrow = 26)
  )
```

Then, pass the numeric portions to `heatmap.2` as a matrix (with out the labelling column), and pass in the labels explictly:

```
heatmap.2(
  as.matrix(df[, -1])
  , labRow = df$target_id__ext_gene
)
```

Produces:

[image]

Which you can further modify with the other settings you want.

Comment: I understand that rnorm function is generating random numbers whose distribution is normal, but howcome mean is 50 and sd is 5. For my data, I don't know the values for mean and sd or I need to calculate. Or as per [link](cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/probability.html) mean and sd are optional arguments.  So I used `df <- unite(target_id__ext_gene = LETTERS, matrix(rnorm(100*9), nrow = 100))` because I have 100 rows and 9 columns. I got this error: **Error in unite(target_id__ext_gene = LETTERS, matrix(rnorm(100 * 9), : unused argument (target_id__ext_gene = LETTERS)**

Comment: I just played around and was able to do that without rnorm and with updated `heatmap.2`.   Here it is   `>heatmap.2(log(as.matrix(unite[, -1]) + 1), labRow = unite$target_id__ext_gene, trace="none", density.info="none", xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, main = "Heatmap", col=redgreen(75), margins = c(5.5, 8), scale="row", cexCol = 0.8, cexRow=0.5)`.

Comment: The construction of `df` was only to show an example, which was necessitated because you did not provide reproducible data. Thus, it will not (obviously) match your actual data. Also: yes, what you wrote in the comment is the extension of my answer to match your actual data. The options beyond `labRow` are, however, not part of the MCVE of your problem (hence why I omitted them in my answer).